# Getting the total sum of radial button values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the sum of all radial buttons selected. There are three groups of three in total with a possibility of three checked. These are created by the Angular `ng-repeat` that you will see in the index page.

I have lurked through many posts saying that they have found a way to do this, but I still don't get the output that I need. I know that the jQuery is running because I tested that. So I don't know what is going in.

Please see if you can spot or suppose what is going on. Thank you The code looks horrendous and uneven but this is because the box keeps screwing the hierarchy of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Cruiseline</title>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {


          $(".all_aboard").click(".radial_input", function() {
            var total = 0;
            $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
              total += parseFloat($(this).val());
              });

            $(".totalSum").val(total);
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%= yield %>
    </body>
    </html>
<h1 class="title">Choose Your Sailings&nbsp;<span class="pick_one">(Pick one for each box)</span></h1>
<div class="all_aboard" ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="CruisesController">
      <div ng-repeat="cruise in cruises">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">                
            <div ng-controller="SailingsController">
                <div ng-repeat="sail in sailings ">
                    <div ng-if="sail.cruise_id == cruise.id">
                <div>
                  <img src="{{ sail.main_image }}" class="cruise_picture"/>
                  <img><%= image_tag "lowest_price_tag.png", class: "lowest_price_tag"%> <img/>
                </div>                      
                <div class="cruise_details">{{cruise.name}}-{{cruise.ship_name}}</div>
                        <h1 class="sailing_title">{{ sail.name }}</h1>
                        <div ng-controller="SailingOptionsController">
                            <div class="option_box" ng-repeat="soption in sailing_options">
                                <div ng-if="soption.sailing_id == sail.id" >
                                 <div class="radio">
                                  <input class="radial_input" id="soption{{soption.id}}" type="radio" name="cruisePrice{{sail.id}}" data-price="{{soption.price}}">
                                  <div class="date">{{ soption.date}}</div>
                                  <div class="price">${{ soption.price}}</div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div>
  <h1 class="you_selected_total">You Selected Sailings Total</h1>
  <input style="color:red;" type="text" class="totalSum" value="" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Comment: see: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ i'd assume, that the event binding on the input elements takes place, before the elements exist, since ng-repeat injects them dynamically into the dom. therefore you need to bind the click event on some superior element and filter the subset. $(".all_aboard").click(".radial_input", function() {}

Comment: Interesting. I thought, this was certainly my salvation as it makes sense. However, I tried what you proposed and I still don't get the data... I even added a document.ready call to make sure that the whole thing is loaded before the function is executed.

Comment: sry... was to early in the morning... had an error - not .click, but .on("click", ".radial_input", function{}); ;)

Comment: No worries, I get the feeling. I have not known the sweet release of sleep for two days now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

I updated answer now try

```
$(".all_aboard").on("click",".radial_input", function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(document).find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {

              total += parseFloat($(this).parent().find('.price').text());
          });

        $(".totalSum").val(total);
      });
```

Comment: I get an output! NaN but is more than I have gotten for last three hours. I only get this NaN value when I pass it with the $(document).ready call. By itself, I don't get even the NaN value. I may be passing the number as a json varaible, with would still have "quotations" around it and therefore be a string. Now I need to figure out how to trim those away.

Comment: change `$(".all_aboard").on("click",".radial_input"` to `$(document).on("click",".all_aboard .radial_input"`

Comment: I am still getting NaN, which suggest further errors on my part. I will have to check further into the price attribute output

Comment: PROBLEM IS THAT YOU DIDN'T SPECIFY VALUE IN YOUR RADIO INPUT

Comment: Lol you are right. I knew it the moment I opened my eyes an hour ago. I didn't have to look at the code at all. This is why sleep is important.

Comment: I am putting this as the answer as the $(document).on("click", ".all abour .radial_input" was the first work. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of things in your code.

First, if you are using jQuery to make things work, you should wrap it up in a `$(document).ready(function() {});` like below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
      var total = 0;
      $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
         total += parseFloat($(this).val());
      });

      $(".totalSum").val(total);
   });
});
```

If you are planning to add more radio buttons using code, then you should consider using jQuery '[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)' to bind events.

Next, you should use check boxes instead of radio buttons if you are trying to enable multiple select (I am assuming you are, since you are looking to get a total).

Next, try and minimize direct use of jQuery when developing your angular applications: it can lead to lot of confusions and unwanted scenarios like your angular functions not getting executed, or your angular variables not getting updated.

Finally, take a look at the below fiddle and see if it fits your solution

[JSFiddle: Update Price when Checked](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeHawkz/dh94xbno/)

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will definitely take them into account while I continue my journey with Angular. Unfortunately, I am too mentally ragged to get any new info at this time. I will probably have to make sense of it when my wits are sharper. But it seems like an elegant, posible solution. Especially if I get to use Angular to solve it.

Comment: Did any of the steps I mention help you solve the problem? Even if you use some other solution, you should do the first step i told you, since that's the basics of jQuery

Comment: Thank you, yes. I added the document ready call. As overkill perhaps. I then made a $(document).on("click" , ".all_aboard .radial_input")